# ACF - Retrieve custom taxonomy from a relationship field

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have a custom post type, called `prognosis` with 3 custom taxonomies, **Country**, **Competition**, and **Sport**, I've also added a few ACF custom fields. I have another custom post type called `analysis` with an ACF relationship field `prognosis` connected to the `prognosis` custom post type.

I want to be able to display certain taxonomy/ies the custom post type `prognosis` is connected to, through the relationship field that I have selected in the `analysis` custom post type. I tried debugging the `prognosis` relationship field but I don't see any taxonomies attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my issue by looping through a get_the_terms() function. In my case, I've also created a shortcode.

```
function display_taxonomy() { 

$prognoses = get_field('prognosis');
ob_start();
if( $prognoses ):
foreach( $prognoses as $prognosis ):
    $terms = get_the_terms( $prognosis->ID , 'my_custom_taxonomy' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ):
        echo $term->name;
    endforeach;
endforeach;
endif;
return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'my_custom_taxonomy_shortcode', 'display_taxonomy' );
```